# MySQL.exe won't open?

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I just installed the latest XAMPP with the MariaDB 10.4.24 version on Windows11 latest build. The installation was completely fine except that i got a prompt that says I need to deactivate the UAC if i want to install it in directory C. But i ignore the prompt because i installed it in directory D.
The control panel works just fine, but when i run the mysql.exe it won't open (suddenly closed). I have tried to deactivate the UAC but it keeps force closing.

I'm still a beginner at programming so, any tips?

[image]

Comment: What does the log tell?

Comment: @Raptor the last 2 logs
2022-04-11 10:51:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-04-11 10:51:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

Comment: You can paste the log into your question.

Comment: Your logs and the gui status both show that the MariaDB is running. Stack Overflow tip, you can edit the question after its posted to include more information.